# Overriding precision control within Reclassify Tool of ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.3, reclassify, precision

I have a coding scheme in which I am trying to apply using the Reclassify tool prior to combining the different raster datasets using raster calculator.  I have used the Reclassify tool for other datasets that do not exceed the precision limit; however, I cannot seem to reclassify a new value over 10,000,000,000.  The maximum value I will need to reclassify to is 100,000,000,000.

I have altered the raster data into 64-bit double precision but cannot seem to override the precision control within the Reclassify Tool (will not exceed 9).

Is there anyway to override this control using ArcMap 10.3.1 to accommodate these larger numbers without using ArcPy?

If not, are there any suggestions on how I can make the Value equal those higher values?

I have been working within ModelBuilder.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Sounds like a built-in limitation of the tool.  There may be other tools that allow it (I don't know) but might be worth logging with Esri support or as an idea through Esri Ideas website.  Arcpy *might* get you around it and would be easy to test just by exporting that one tool to python script, modifying the value, and run it

Comment: Sorry forgot to say - you could then add this script back into your model.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, no.

Which is frustrating because the [docs](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm) describe that it has one

> This tool has a precision control that manages how decimal places are
>   treated.

but not how to modify it.